# How should I understand the wording 常有……配合 within 常有“可是、但是、却、然而”等词配合?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

This is part of the grammar explanation for 固然 from the HSK6 Standard Course textbook page 46 ([photo of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jva1F.jpg)).

> （1）下文转折，提出对立的另一事实。后一分句中**常有“可是、但是、却、然而”等词配合**。例如……

It seems like in this sentence 常有 + words + 配合 is some kind of grammar structure.  I'm more used to 配合 meaning "to cooperate", which doesn't make sense here, although it seems to have many additional meanings:

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%85%8D%E5%90%88): 配合 (pèi​hé​) matching / fitting in with / compatible with / to correspond / to fit / to conform to / rapport / to coordinate with / to act in concert with / to cooperate / to become man and wife / to combine parts of machine

The use of 有 suggests 配合 is being used as a noun.  I'm confused both about what 配合 means here, and how the grammar structure 常有 + words + 配合 works.

If I were to write this, I'd be tempted to use the wording 常与……等词搭配.

**Question**: How should I understand the wording 常有……配合?

Answer (score 2):

配合 is a verb. It refers to what the noun phrase in question (*“可是、但是、却、然而”等词*) is there *to do* (ie "to match", "to go with"). The object of this verb is 固然, but it's left implicit because it's the topic of the whole paragraph.

The structure is the same you might see in, say:

那个教科书的问题很多，网上常有朋友解释。

Grammatically, the verb can be interpreted as either a final or a relative clause (it's sequential to its subject and can be either). Respectively, that would yield:

> "In the subsequent clause, there are usually words like [...] *to* match."

or

> "In the subsequent clause, there are usually words like [...] *that* match/pair with it ".

Additionally, you are also free to read 配合 as the main verb, because when the existential 有 is *配合ed* to an active verb, it logically ends up acting as a coverb marking (indefinite) agency, just as it does in ”有人说“. You can therefore translate the sentence in passive form, too:

> "In the subsequent clause, it is usually matched *by* words like [...]."

or, to use a different verb:

> "In the subsequent clause, it is usually paired *to* words like [...]."

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. I would translate this 配合 as "in combination". Could also be "in cooperation" or "combining with".

队员间的**配合**并非强迫命令而成。
You can't enforce cooperation between the players.

下文转折，
In the following passage the plot shifts,
提出对立的另一事实。
suggesting other, contradictory facts.
后一分句中常有“可是、但是、却、然而”等词配合。
in (the) last clause (we) often (see) words like "but, however, while, yet" in combination.
例如……
For example ...

Answer (score 0):

**配合**

[英语] - matching, fitting in with, compatible with, to correspond, to fit, to conform to, rapport, to coordinate with, **to act in concert with**, to cooperate, to become man and wife, to combine parts of machine